# Is it a convention to write ?Sized by itself as a trait bound?

Tags: generics, rust, traits, bounding

On page 297 of [Programming Rust](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920040385.do) you can find the following

```
impl HashMap<K, V> where K: Eq + Hash
{
  fn get<Q: ?Sized>(&self, key: &Q) -> Option<&V>
      where K: Borrow<Q>,
            Q: Eq + Hash
}
```

I've seen this before where `?Sized` is written by itself, and the rest of trait bounds are on a different line? Is this a convention? As I understand it, the above is effectively the same as the following?

```
impl HashMap<K, V> where K: Eq + Hash
{
  fn get<Q>(&self, key: &Q) -> Option<&V>
      where K: Borrow<Q>,
            Q: Eq + Hash + ?Sized
}
```

Why is `?Sized` split off? You can see this in a similar example on [page 295](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58030348/124486),

```
...
where T: AsRef<U>
      T: ?Sized, U: ?Sized
...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is pure convention, and it is not set in stone, but it does have some merit.

The special syntax `?Sized` lets the compiler remove this bound if it is not appropriate (when monomorphizing). As such, it does make sense, somewhat, to split it and put it in the generic definition rather than the `where` clause for ease of readability and to separate the fact that, unlike the others, it isn't a strict, rigid marker.

Some libraries out there go even further and list all the markers in the generic definition, and all traits in the `where` clause.

As stated in the comments and found by @PeterHall through the commit log, prior to rust 1.15, `?Sized` was only available as a trait requirement in the type definition. [This PR](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/37791) changed this to the behavior we have today.

Comment: There are also historical reasons for this distinction, though. Early versions of the compiler did not allow for `?Sized` to be in the `where` clause.

Comment: @E_net4theMeta-RemoveR that is probably the "real" answer.

Comment: @PeterHall I would turn it info an answer if I found the reference. All I know is word of mouth that I still haven't quite validated yet.

Comment: @E_net4theMeta-RemoveR https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/37791 Stable in Rust 1.15

Comment: So you found it. :)

Comment: Edited the answer to include this detail