# What is the point of an explicit lifetime for a method that doesn't take any arguments?

Tags: rust, lifetime, lifetime-scoping

On page 295 of [Programming Rust](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920040385.do) you can find the following:

> Fortunately, the standard library includes the blanket implementation:
>
> ```
> impl<'a, T, U> AsRef<U> for &'a T
> where
>     T: AsRef<U>,
>     T: ?Sized,
>     U: ?Sized,
> {
>     fn as_ref(&self) -> &U {
>         (*self).as_ref()
>     }
> }
> ```

I'm confused at the use of `&'a` there. What is the context of that? It's not being used in an argument of `as_ref` nor tied to the output of `&U`. I don't think I fully understand lifetimes when used in this context.

I looked this up because I still didn't understand it and the answers still weren't clicking (making sense). I found [`convert.rs`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.37.0/src/core/convert.rs.html). This doesn't seem to have *any* lifetimes anywhere, but it implements the `AsRef` trait. So why does the book have this, and not the actual code in Rust? Where can I find the "blanket implementation" mentioned in the book?

Comment: *and not the actual code in Rust* — are you aware that Rust releases new versions every 6 weeks? Presumably the book does not, so *what version of Rust are they citing*?

Comment: @Shepmaster step back, I'm new. Why would there be a difference? My question is simply that I don't understand the lifetime use in the book, and going to see the code I don't see it there (which is what I would expect). Why did it change (if it did).

Comment: *Why did it change (if it did)* — that's covered by [an existing answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58030681/155423): *There used to be a time when there was no possibility for lifetime elision in implementation statements. This changed in version 1.31 of the compiler*

Comment: I do think you come off with questions that are obvious. **Of course** I realize books can be out of date. I just wanted to see the comparison between the *blanket implementation* the book has and the new one, and you provided it at the same time I had asked this question, so I think I communicated my confusion. I just didn't have the Rust expertise to know that the code in your answer was the replacement. (Mostly because when I mentally elided `&'a T` I dropped `&'a` and I went looking for `T` instead of `&T` and then was confused because I thought it only worked on functions and not impls.

Comment: @Shepmaster anyway, thanks again for the answer ;)

Comment: I don't see what question I asked was obvious. I didn't ask if you knew the book could be out of date. I asked if you knew that (1) Rust releases frequently (C and C++ releases are every 3-5 years, for comparison, so it's more likely that a book would correspond to the most recent release) and (2) what version the book uses. The first isn't obvious and the second isn't something that is general knowledge (and I don't own that book).

Comment: Fair enough, perhaps I read into it wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> It's not being used in an argument of `as_ref`

It most certainly is. The function uses a shorthand notation, which can be expanded:

```
fn as_ref(&self) // becomes
fn as_ref(self: &Self) // becomes
fn as_ref(self: &&'a T)
```

> nor tied to the output of `&U`

Correct.

> So why does the book have this, and not the actual code in Rust?

Rust releases new stable versions every 6 weeks. Presumably the book does not, so it is likely that they are using an older version of Rust. Hopefully the book tells you the version they developed with.

As [E_net4 already stated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58030681/155423), the requirement to specify the `'a` in this case was removed in Rust 1.31, as [documented in the edition guide](https://doc.rust-lang.org/edition-guide/rust-2018/ownership-and-lifetimes/lifetime-elision-in-impl.html).

The code you provide from the book matches that [found in Rust 1.30](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/1.30.0/src/libcore/convert.rs#L410-L415):

> ```
> impl<'a, T: ?Sized, U: ?Sized> AsRef<U> for &'a T where T: AsRef<U>
> {
>     fn as_ref(&self) -> &U {
>         <T as AsRef<U>>::as_ref(*self)
>     }
> }
> ```

The source code you looked at [corresponds to Rust 1.37](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/1.37.0/src/libcore/convert.rs#L494-L499):

> ```
> impl<T: ?Sized, U: ?Sized> AsRef<U> for &T where T: AsRef<U>
> {
>     fn as_ref(&self) -> &U {
>         <T as AsRef<U>>::as_ref(*self)
>     }
> }
> ```

This is about 42 weeks of development time, plenty for the source code to have changed.

Comment: I like this answer because this shows all aspects including the relevant changes to `convert.rs`. I also see that `&'a T` (and not `&'a &T`) is `&T`. Anyway, I think I'm closer to wrapping my head around this now. thanks

Answer (score 4):

References are always generic to a lifetime. In practice, a `&T` is always a `&'a T` for some lifetime established by the compiler according to the given circumstances. This lifetime has to be specified in *some way* when implementing something for a reference type.

There used to be a time when there was no possibility for lifetime elision in implementation statements. This changed in version [1.31](https://blog.rust-lang.org/2018/12/06/Rust-1.31-and-rust-2018.html#more-lifetime-elision-rules) of the compiler, but there was no need to change all existing, working code because of this. The code below works today, but not in version 1.30.0:

```
trait Foo {
    fn foo(&self) {}
}

impl<T: ?Sized> Foo for &T {} // error[E0106]: missing lifetime specifier
```

As such, the lifetime parameter `'a` was made explicit in this case. The only way it relates from the lifetimes in `&self` and `&U` is that there will be covariance with `'a`: since `self = &'a T` is bound to the lifetime `'a`, it is also implicit that `&self` must not outlive the lifetime `'a`.